# Reproject MODIS level 3 chlorophyll data using gdal

Tags: gdal, r, remote-sensing, modis

I am trying to reproject MODIS Level 3 chlorophyll data (for instance, [this file](http://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/A20121832012213.L3m_MO_CHL_chlor_a_4km)) using `gdal` in R.

I used `gdal_translate` and `gdalwarp` functions. There was no crs information associated with A20121832012213.L3m_MO_CHL_chlor_a_4km.hdf file.

I used:

```
s_srs= "+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +units=m +no_defs +R=6371007.181"

gdalwarp(source,dest,
s_srs="+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +units=m +no_defs +R=6371007.181",
t_srs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0",srcnodata=-32767,dstnodata=NA)
```

Although `gdal_translate` can translate hdf file to other formats, like img, this file cannot be reprojected by `gdalwarp` because there is an error:

> GeoTransform values not available which is returned by function
>   GetGeoTransform

PS:
Description of Level 3 data says:

> This image is typically a scaled value (16bit), two-dimensional array of an Equidistant Cylindrical projection of the globe.

However MODIS Level 3 data is different from SeaWifs Level 3 data. There is no problem with reprojecting SeaWifs data, but not MODIS.

Comment: Which projection do you want?

Answer (score 3):

After all I found solution, but not sure if that is right and elegant.

I used proj4 string that SeaWifs level 3 have:

```
s_srs="+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
```

and overwrite georeferenced bounds by the values from SeaWifs hdf file

```
a_ullr =c(-20037508.343,10018754.171,20037508.343,-10018754.171)
```

after this gdal_translate creates img with GeoTransform values

```
gdal_translate("A20121832012213.L3m_MO_CHL_chlor_a_4km.hdf", "A20121832012213.L3m_MO_CHL_chlor_a_4km.img", of="HFA",b=1,a_srs="+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs",a_ullr =c(-20037508.343,10018754.171,20037508.343,-10018754.171))
```

and gdalwarp can reproject this file

```
gdalwarp("A20121832012213.L3m_MO_CHL_chlor_a_4km.img","A20121832012213.L3m_MO_CHL_chlor_a_4km_reprojected.img",t_srs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0",srcnodata=-32767,dstnodata=NA)
```

Reprojection looks pretty accurate. If somebody can prove that this approach is acceptable?

Comment: You are basically assuming that your dataset uses the (deprecated) WGS 84 / Plate Carree projection (EPSG: 32662; http://epsg.io/32662), which is correct according to this document: http://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/DOCS/Ocean_Level-3_SMI_Products.pdf. Side remark: there apparently is some confusion about Plate Carree and World Equidistant Cylindrical. EPSG:4087 (http://epsg.io/4087) is the current code for WGS 84 / World Equidistant Cylindrical, but uses different projected bounds and would therefore result in a north-south shift when applied to the dataset in question.